# cannot update a column depending on other column in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview, grid has 5 different columns ID,FirstName,LastName,DateOfBirth and Age, gridview can be edited, so I want to update the Age depending on DateOfBirth column so I have written the necessary functionality in OnRowBound function.When i execute the grid view page I get "String is not Recognized as valid datetime".

Here is the Function of OnRowBound

```
 protected void UserInfoGrid_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            DateTime DOBOnGrid = DateTime.ParseExact(e.Row.Cells[3].Text,"MM/dd/yyyy",null);
            Label tAge = (Label)e.Row.Cells[4].FindControl("txtAge");

            TimeSpan ts = DateTime.Now - DOBOnGrid;
            int CurrAge = ts.Days / 365;
            tAge.Text = CurrAge.ToString();
        }
    }

  <asp:GridView ID="UserInfoGrid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="3"
            DataKeyNames="userid" DataSourceID="DataSrcUserInfo"
            AllowPaging="True" OnRowDataBound="UserInfoGrid_RowDataBound"
            OnRowUpdated="Update" OnRowDeleted="Delete" PageSize="10" >
```

can anyone help me with this

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, shouldn't the code your are showing be in the `RowUpdating` event handler? As for the error you are getting, its obviously due to a bad formatted string in the Birthday cell.

Have you checked for empty strings? I'm guessing you are getting the exception even before the `GridView` renders on screen as its in the `RowDataBound` event handler which fires when the GridView is loading.